# How to combine subarrays within an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How would I combine the subarrays within this array

```
[["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0"], ["1"]]
```

I want to add a comma in between each subarrays so that it would read
`000,000,1`.

I have tried using `*","` but it will combine the whole array together and give me `0,0,0,0,0,0,1` instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `000,000,1 ` is not an object. Is it `"000,000,1"`, or `["000","000","1"]` or something else?

Answer (score 4):

First join the inner arrays:

```
 array.map(&:join)
 # => ["000", "000", "1"]
```

That join that array, but this time with a `,` as a separator:

```
 array = ["000", "000", "1"]
 array.join(',')
 # => "000,000,1"
```

Or as a one liner:

```
 array = [["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0"], ["1"]]
 array.map(&:join).join(',')
 # => "000,000,1"
```